# what is the proper way to update the XY model for a Metropolis MC simulation

Tags: python, monte-carlo, statistics

I am trying to do a 2D simulation of the classical XY model in order to observe vortexes in the system.
I am not really interested at the moment in calculating variables such as Magnetization because i am struggling to evolve the model. Probably because of the update step misinterpretation.

Here is how i proceed, keeping in mind i have worked only with the classical Ising model.

1. I start with a randomly generated field of spins. from -pi to pi
2. I move along each lattice site in sequential order and do the update step.

- In the update step, since the spins can take values in the whole circle, i create a perturbation term called **delta_theta** which is chosen from a uniform distribution between -pi and pi. I multiply the perturbation term by **0.1** to keep the change small.
- I check the energy change ONLY for the lattice site i am currently at in the iteration. I calculate the Energy based on the Nearest Neighbor interaction (calculate energy for up, down, left, right lattice sites).
- Depending on the energy, i keep the newly perturbed spin value if dE < 0 or if a randomly generated number falls under the probability steps of the Metropolis algorithm. If these are not fulfilled the **delta_theta** perturbation is subtracted from the spin value so that it returns to its original local equilibrium state.

3. Repeat until maximum iterations are achieved or until something of interest happens.

The code is as follows

```
%load_ext Cython
```

```
%%cython

cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libc.math cimport exp, cos, pi



ctypedef np.float64_t dtype_t



from libc.stdlib cimport rand, srand, RAND_MAX


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.initializedcheck(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cdef dtype_t xy_energy(dtype_t[:, ::1] field, int n, int m, int N, int M, dtype_t J):
    cdef dtype_t angle_diff = field[n, m] - field[n % N, (m+1) % M]
    angle_diff += field[n, m] - field[(n+1) % N, m % M]
    angle_diff += field[n, m] - field[n % N, (m-1) % M]
    angle_diff += field[n, m] - field[(n-1) % N, m % M]

    cdef dtype_t dE = 2.0 * J * cos(angle_diff) * field[n, m]
    return dE


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.initializedcheck(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cdef dtype_t[:, ::1] xy_update(dtype_t[:, ::1] main_array, int N, int M, dtype_t beta, dtype_t J):
    cdef size_t i, j
    cdef dtype_t current_energy, delta_theta, energy_difference

    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(M):
            current_energy = xy_energy(main_array, i, j, N, M, beta, J)
            delta_theta = 0.1 * (rand() / RAND_MAX) * 2 * pi - pi

            main_array[i, j] += delta_theta
            energy_difference = xy_energy(main_array, i, j, N, M, beta, J) - current_energy

            if energy_difference > 0:
                main_array[i, j] -= delta_theta
            elif exp(-energy_difference * beta) <= (rand() / RAND_MAX):
                main_array[i, j] -= delta_theta

    return main_array


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.initializedcheck(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cpdef double[:, ::1] xy_solve(int max_iter, double[:, ::1] field, double beta, double J):
    cdef int N = field.shape[0]
    cdef int M = field.shape[1]
    cdef int _it

    cdef double[:, ::1] arr = field

    for _it in range(max_iter):
        arr = xy_update(arr, N, M, beta, J)

    return arr
```

Now to make a test in another Cell

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

row = 200
col = 300

initial = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, size=(row, col))
```

```
%%time
test = xy_solve(500, initial, 0.4, 1)
```

Code ran in 2seconds and gave off following result.

Initial Array::
[image: random spins]

Final computed array::
[image: aligned spins]

Expected Result:: (courtesy of wikipedia)
[image]

It is evidently clear here one spin is starting to dominate and there are no regions of local equilibrium being created that have vortex anti-vortex pairs on their edges

Here J is set to 1 and Beta to 0.4

I have tried various values for Beta from 0.0001 to 300 with little success and in some cases some very funny scenarios.

Can somebody tell me if i am doing anything wrong or if the methodology is flawed? Because online there are neigh zero articles on the classical XY model that explain how the update step is done. Only the results.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that using a step size of 0.1 is right? Have you checked the acceptance / rejection ratio? Despite the fact that MCMC converges according to the math, the rate can be so slow that it basically takes forever.

Comment: @DanielShapero 
No i am not sure i am trying varying coefficients for J, beta and perturbation sizes. Including straight up flipping the spin like in the Ising.
Will put a reply tomorrow if i find success

Comment: Ok, this might also be a big change in scope so take this suggestion with a grain of salt. Regular old Metropolis-Hastings can be really slow in high dimensions and it only uses your ability to calculate the energy. There are other methods like [MALA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis-adjusted_Langevin_algorithm) that converge much faster by using both the energy functional and its derivative. There are of course more demands on you to be able to use this but it could be worth it.

Comment: Good afternoon,
I just found your question and I was wondering if you ever found a solution to your problem?
I'm currently trying to do a similar simulation and I have run into a similar problem.
There is either one spin starting to dominate (like in your final picture, this always happens when I add an external magnetic field), or it seems that there's no order whatsoever (any time I don't apply an external field).
The code itself does work, but I think there must be something wrong with the update step or my initial parameters.
It would be great if you had an answer!